# Enabling USB debugging in recovery mode in rooted Android

Tags: recovery-mode, usb-debugging, samsung-galaxy-note-2

My Samsung Galaxy Note 2 is rooted. After I installed some apps, my phone crashed and would keep giving errors. I want to access my phone data like pics from my PC, but the USB debugging is off and I can only switch on in the recovery mode.

Is there any way to back up my data before I factory reset?

Comment: By default TWRP starts mtp when you boot into recovery. Boot into recovery connect your phone to your pc and if your drivers are configured properly you will be easily able to get back all you lost.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but found this solution on [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2335799):

Add to `default.prop` and `/system/build.prop`

```
persist.service.adb.enable=1                                                  
persist.service.debuggable=1
persist.sys.usb.config=mtp,adb
```